# How do I put this on Real-Time? I already put (async: True) but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js, real-time

I finally made it working with AJAX but the problem is, it's not real-time whenever I change some data in phpMyAdmin, I need to refresh it on the website.

Here's my code: **ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/projectZeus/private/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            var energy = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                energy.push(data[i].energyPercent);
            }   

            var chartdata = {
                labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Harvested",
                    lineTension: 0.3,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                    pointRadius: 6,
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
                    pointHoverRadius: 8,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                    pointHitRadius: 20,
                    pointBorderWidth: 2,
                    data: energy
                }]
            };

            var ctx = $("#AreaChart");

            var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Here's my code in **data.php**

```
<?php
require_once('initialize.php');

header('Content-Type: application/json');
global $db;

$sql = "SELECT energyPercent FROM energy";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$data = array();
foreach($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

echo json_encode($data);
```

?>

**How can I get it to real-time without refreshing the page? Please help, thanks!**

Answer (score 6):

Instead of polling, you can use server-sent-events, which does not put as much strain on the server as data is only sent if a new event has happened (like a new row). More can be found out about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Here is an example, as the one in the link is not that good.

The result will look like the following gif:

[image]

**chart.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Server-sent events demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="chart_div"></div>

    <button>Close the connection</button>

    <script>
        // google chart function
        function chart(chart_data) {
            google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

            function drawBasic() {

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('number', 'X');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

                data.addRows(chart_data);

                var options = {
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Time'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Popularity'
                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        }

        // stop button
        var button = document.querySelector('button');

        // the rest is the EventSource, simplez.. 
        var evtSource = new EventSource('sse.php', { withCredentials: true });

        evtSource.onopen = function() {
            chart([])
        }

        evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
            chart(JSON.parse(e.data))
        }

        evtSource.onerror = function() {
            console.log("EventSource failed.");
        }

        button.onclick = function() {
            console.log('Connection closed');
            evtSource.close();
        }

        /**
        * or you could use addEventListener's to listen to specific events, like event: chartdata (or incase you wanted to send multiple events in the same stream)
        */
        //   evtSource.addEventListener("ping", function(e) {
        //      // do somthing with JSON.parse(e.data)
        //   }, false);      

        //   evtSource.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        //      // do somthing with JSON.parse(e.data)
        //   }, false);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Then the event loop, note that this is not an infinite loop nor do you need to maintain it, it will get created once a client connects and exit once the client disconnects.

**sse.php**

```
<?php
// no normal requests
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] !== 'text/event-stream') {
    exit();
}

// make session read-only
session_start();
session_write_close();

// disable default disconnect checks
ignore_user_abort(true);

// set headers for stream
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

// a new stream or an existing one
$lastEventId = intval(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"] : 0);

if ($lastEventId === 0) {
    // resume from a previous event
    $lastEventId = intval(isset($_GET["lastEventId"]) ? $_GET["lastEventId"] : 0);
}

echo ":".str_repeat(" ", 2048)."\n"; // Padding for IE
echo "retry: 2000\n";

// query initial data, or select by event id
$data = [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 5],
    [2, 15],
    [3, 45],
    [4, 34],
    [5, 21],
];

// mock we at event 6
$lastEventId = 6;

// start stream
while (true) {

    // user disconnected, kill process
    if (connection_aborted()) {
        exit();
    } else {

    // force an update, normally you would assign ids to your events/data
    $latestEventId = $lastEventId+1;

    //
    if ($lastEventId < $latestEventId) {

        // generate some data, use array_shift() before to limit array leght whilst rolling
        $data[] = [$latestEventId, rand(0, 100)];

        echo "id: " . $latestEventId . "\n";
        echo "event: message\n";
        echo "data: ".json_encode($data)."\n\n";

        $lastEventId = $latestEventId;
    } else {
        echo "event: ping\n";
    }
  }

  // flush buffer
  ob_flush();
  flush();

  // 2 second sleep
  sleep(2);
}
```

Hope it helps, avoid polling its 2018!

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'm still confused though, i'll research on that

Comment: Heres a simple chat script made with the same idea: https://github.com/lcherone/sse-chat-example

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set a timer, then execute your ajax call every n seconds/minutes, but this is expensive if your data is too large/big. I recommend using **web socket**, as this will only one time open a bridge connection from your server side to your client side, then it will just cost minimal resources to transfer data between.

ref for php web socket: http://socketo.me/

Or just do the timer thing with your javascript:

```
setInterval(function() {
   //call your ajax function here
}, 5 * 1000) //1000 millisecond = 1 second, so multiply by 5 for 5 seconds
```

Comment: At least you mentioned websockets, also server sent events as there is no need for 2-way data.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, maybe I should read more about how it works. hehe.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do this (there is much more, I know). the first is you create a javascript function that executes this request from time to time, (this will cost processing).

```
function functionAjax () {
    console.log ('Running');
}
var interval = setInterval (Ajax function, 3000);
```

the other is you study something that is fashionable, RXJS, a javascript technology, you will need a good time to study.
If it is only for study, I recommend [FireBase (google technology) in which it provides this database in real time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

[RxJs documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)

Simple Ajax implementation with RxJS

And always remember to search before posting anything, maybe you find the answer that you are looking for, good study =)