# Upgrading my PHP chat system? (Making it only update new messages?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

JS:

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function () {
    var chatInterval = 250; //refresh interval in ms
    var $userName = $("#userName");
    var $chatOutput = $("#chatOutput");
    var $chatInput = $("#chatInput");
    var $chatSend = $("#chatSend");

    function sendMessage() {
        var userNameString = $userName.val();
        var chatInputString = $chatInput.val();

        $.get("./write.php", {
            username: userNameString,
            text: chatInputString
        });

        $userName.val("");
        retrieveMessages();
    }

    function retrieveMessages() {
        $.get("./read.php", function (data) {
            $chatOutput.html(data); //Paste content into chat output
        });
    }


    $chatSend.click(function () {
        sendMessage();
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        retrieveMessages();
    }, chatInterval);
});
```

Write.php:

```
<?php
require("connect.php");

//connect to db
$db = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    //if the connection to the db failed
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}


//get userinput from url
$username=substr($_GET["username"], 0, 32);
$text=substr($_GET["text"], 0, 128);
//escaping is extremely important to avoid injections!
$nameEscaped = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$username)); //escape username and limit it to 32 chars
$textEscaped = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $text)); //escape text and limit it to 128 chars



//create query
$query="INSERT INTO chat (username, text) VALUES ('$nameEscaped', '$textEscaped')";
//execute query
if ($db->real_query($query)) {
    //If the query was successful
    echo "Wrote message to db";
}else{
    //If the query was NOT successful
    echo "An error occured";
    echo $db->errno;
}

$db->close();
?>
```

Read.php

```
<?php
require("connect.php");

//connect to db
$db = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user, $db_password, $db_name); 
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    //if the connection to the db failed
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}


$query="SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id ASC";
//execute query
if ($db->real_query($query)) {
    //If the query was successful
    $res = $db->use_result();

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $username=$row["username"];
        $text=$row["text"];
        $time=date('G:i', strtotime($row["time"])); //outputs date as # #Hour#:#Minute#

        echo "<p>$time | $username: $text</p>\n";
    }
}else{
    //If the query was NOT successful
    echo "An error occured";
    echo $db->errno;
}

$db->close();
?>
```

Basically everything works perfectly, except I want to allow people to copy and paste, but what the script is doing at the moment is updating every message at the chatinterval which is 250MS.

How can I make it so I can highlight a message and copy it?

**So my question is, can I do this:**

*Can I make it only update the new messages that appear every 250-500MS instead of updating every last bit of HTML as that is a waste of resources (Especially if there was a lot of messages)*

I hope you can help!

p.s. I don't want to use web sockets

Comment: Polling every 1/4 of a second is silly hopefully not more then 5 people use the chat, if not websockets, you could use server sent events, which is much more efficient than polling. You wouldn't need to change much either. Fix your sql injctions and XSS before it too late.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone How do I use server sent events? Could you show me

Comment: Heres an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080653/how-do-i-put-this-on-real-time-i-already-put-async-true-but-it-doesnt-work/49081040#49081040

Comment: no websocket with request 250ms, really?? basically you ddos your own server with your request

Comment: Another example here https://github.com/lcherone/sse-chat-example

Answer (score 2):

To make it update just starting from the last message, get the ID of the last message, and then in your next `$.get` include the id of that message and get only messages that came after that.

And then use `.append()` in your javascript so you're not overwriting the whole thing.

Comment: What do you mean? How do I make it just update the new messages, could you explain a bit better for me?

Comment: Have a hidden input field like so `<input type="hidden" id="lastMessageId" value="109832">`

Then, each time you poll for new messages, just include the value for that field and in your query ONLY get messages after that one. Then, append the results to your existing messages rather than over writing them. Also, be sure to update that input field.

Comment: @Difster would probably be easier to avoid adding another input field, and just attach a `data` attribute to each message `<p>`.

Comment: @wolfson Yes that is smart wolfson

Comment: That would work too @wolfson but I didn't want to introduce a whole new complexity to the user.

Comment: fair enough, it's all tradeoffs ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already using jQuery. You can create a PHP script that only queries the database for entries newer than the newest one displayed, then use `$.append` to append the message to the `<div>` (or whatever other element) that holds it.

Also, as the commenter pointed out, you're still probably susceptible to SQL injection. Considering using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with [prepared SQL statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: How do I do this? SELECT * FROM DATE? (How does it know what messages are the latest ones and which aren't?)

Comment: How do I detect which messages have already been received by the user in order to only select the new messages?

Comment: As @Difster pointed out, you can only select messages newer than the latest one displayed on the screen. Do you have an `id` field in your messages table?

Comment: You can add custom attributes to the `<p>` that holds the message, i.e. `<p class="message" data-id="[message id]">` then use jQuery selectors to select the last `message` class and lookup its `id`.

Comment: Yes I have an ID